# How to hide/show element in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, authentication, meteor

In my Meteor app I have a template with two divs: register and login. The code is as follows:

```
  <div class="login">
    <h1> Log in. </h1>
    <a href"#">Create an account</a>
  </div>

  <div class="register">
    <h1> Register. </h1>
    <a href"#">Log in</a>
  </div>
```

At first, the page should display the "login" div (which will eventually have a form in it) and the "register" div will be hidden from view. However, when I click "Create an account," the "login" div should disappear, and the "register" div should appear. At this point, if I click on "Log in" the reverse should happen.

Essentially, I just want to be able to switch between the login and register forms on the same page. I have tried this using {{#if}} and a click event, but this was not successful.

Anyone have an idea of how to do this?

Comment: You do this with a combination of `{{#if}}` and a helper. Can you be more specific about what you want?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a easy solution and a hardcode solution to achieve this.

The **easy solution** its use the [accounts-ui](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/accounts-ui) package, and just use the

`{{> loginButtons}}` helper into the HTML, this actually have the expected behavior you wants.

And the **hard way**

On the hard way exists 2 possible solutions, using simple jQuery code, and Css. like this.

**jQuery and CSS solution**

Using the Same HTML you have on the example, use this 2 events handlers.

```
Template.example.events({
  'click #aRegister':function(){
    $(".login").css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $(".register").css('visibility', 'visible');

    },
     'click #aLogin':function(){
    $(".register").css('visibility', 'hidden');
     $(".login").css('visibility', 'visible');
    }
  })
```

And this .css

```
.register{
    visibility: hidden;
  }
```

Here is the [MeteorPad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/HTAsEXkkJe79MbA4R/Leaderboard)

**Meteor Way (using Sessions and #if)**

First using the same 2 events we use some Sessions Variables, to set to `true/false` the value of the session, like this.

```
Template.example.events({
  'click #aRegister':function(){
  Session.set('showRegister',true);
    },
     'click #aLogin':function(){
    Session.set('showRegister',false);
    }
  })
```

Now on the HTML we use the [{{#if}}](http://meteorcapture.com/spacebars/#if-else)

```
<template name="example">
{{#if showTheRegisterDiv}}
  <!-- Here if the Session returns its == true this part of the template will be rendered -->
  <div class="register">
    <h1> Register. </h1>
    <a href="#" id="aLogin">Log in</a>
  </div>
 {{else}}
  <!-- or if its == false we render this part -->
  <div class="login">
    <h1> Log in. </h1>
    <a href="#" id="aRegister">Create an account</a>
  </div>
{{/if}}
</template>
```

And this finally works thanks to this template helper.

```
Template.example.helpers({
    showTheRegisterDiv:function(){
        return Session.get('showRegister')
    }
})
```

Here is the [MeteorPad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/rmQKJJjL8bdGBst9a/Leaderboard)

Comment: The second solution worked perfectly! I had tried a variety of helper formats to set the #if variable to true and false, but this is the only one that worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
<body>
  {{#if displayLogin}}

  <div class="login">
    <h1> Log in. </h1>
    <a href"#">Create an account</a>
  </div>

  {{else}}

  <div class="register">
    <h1> Register. </h1>
    <a href"#">Log in</a>
  </div>

  {{/if}}
</body>
```

Then, the helper will just check a session variable:

```
  Template.body.helpers({
    displayLogin: function () {
      return Session.get('displayLogin');
    }
  });
```

And, the session variable gets set when the user clicks to switch between the 2

```
      'click #loginButton': function () {
          Session.set("displayLogin", true);
    }    
  'click #registerButton': function () {
          Session.set("displayLogin", false);
    }
```

Something like this is what I recently did with a custom login form... though I was switching between the login form and the actual application, once they logged in... same idea...

Your html would have to have to add buttons or links with ids of loginButton and registerButton for this example to work

I'm just getting started with meteor so forgive if this is a poorly written example...

Answer (score 0):

If you’re using Bootstrap. Try Collapse. Much simpler.

```
<p>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Are you Registered?
  </button>
</p>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  {{> login}}
</div>
```